# is it possible to delete 15 ad groups in one second without PS?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server

I deleted 2 user accounts in AD running on Windows 2016 (pdc), time stamp is around 1:05:00 pm, then the users report cannot access the share drive on a domain member file server.

Then I found in event log shows I deleted over 10 groups in ONE SECOND at 15:05:16, I haven't done such things, and never use script.

1. Apart from operation error, any other possibilities will cause over 10 groups deleted in 1 second which looks not like a human's action ?
2. What reason should use in incident report ?

I Googled, only use PS may cause such action, is this true? Maybe a bug ?

Comment: FYI wrong site: Stack Overflow is for *programming* Q&A. Probably better to ask on [sf]. Just be sure to read the guidelines there, and when you move your question there, be sure to include as much relevant detail as possible (and please leave out all the filler stuff - I deleted a bunch of it from this question, accordingly)

Comment: @David Makogon is right... Now, if you open "Users and Groups" mmc and select 1000 users or groups ans hit the delete key, they will be deleted within 1 second.